# How to get the actual real time dates when passing milliseconds to moment()

Tags: momentjs

import moment from 'moment';

```
const millseconds =21212121221212
const realDate = moment(millseconds) // I want to got the date in the format of DD:MM::YYYY but I didn't get anything
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
moment(1318781876406).format('DD:MM::YYYY')
```

Prints this:

```
09:03::2642
```

This should give you respective moment date in local date time format

> Note: If you are using moment.js in new project consider reading [this](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)